# Union of arbitrary path connected sets is necessarily a path connected?

Tags: general-topology

Assume $X$ is a topological space that does not have a countable dense set. Let $\{ A_\alpha \}$ be an arbitrary set of path connected sets such that if $\alpha$, $\beta$ are two different indices then $A_\alpha$ is different from $A_\beta$ and that for every $\alpha$ there exists $\beta$ such that $A_\alpha $ intersects $A_\beta$.Then does it necessarily follow that the arbitrary union of these $A_\alpha$'s is path connected? If it is not do please provide a counterexample and also a hint as to how to strengthen the conditions so that the result holds ,without removing the condition that the $X$ does not have any countable dense set if possible of course.

Comment: Your assumptions are way too weak. One way for that to be true is when $\bigcap A_\alpha\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: @freakish What about intuitively forming a chain of them "connected" to each other will that still be a weak condition although i am still not sure how to formalize iit

Comment: Such condition makes sense when $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha=0}^\infty$ is countable and $A_\alpha\cap A_{\alpha+1}\neq\emptyset$. But even then it is not clear to me why $\bigcup A_\alpha$ has to be path connected, although I don't have a counterexample. Regardless, this will fail for arbitrary subcollection, even when $\{A_\alpha\}$ is finite, e.g. $[0,1]$, $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$ but $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take four closed path-connected sets $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$ such that $A_1$ intersects $A_2$ and $A_3$ intersects $A_4$, but $A_1 \cup A_2$ is disjoint from $A_3 \cup A_4$. These satisfy your conditions, but  $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4$  is not connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you also comment on whether intuitively chaining them together subsequently after each other would somehow remedy this?